# How to make React Three Fiber (R3f) model Pop out?

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am trying to make a landing page for tshirt store using vite+react+R3f . I just want to make my model pop up or out .I got my div as flex to get the basic layout .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1yEa.png)This is what i have done so far

Comment: What do you mean by "pop out" ?